# Faster way to capture regex

Tags: regex, r, performance, apply

I want to use regex to capture substrings - I already have a working solution, but I wonder if there is a faster solution. I am applying `applyCaptureRegex` on a vector with about 400.000 entries.

```
 exampleData <- as.data.frame(c("[hg19:21:34809787-34809808:+]","[hg19:11:105851118-105851139:+]","[hg19:17:7482245-7482266:+]","[hg19:6:19839915-19839936:+]"))

captureRegex <- function(captRegEx,str){
  sapply(regmatches(str,gregexpr(captRegEx,str))[[1]], function(m) regmatches(m,regexec(captRegEx,m)))
}

applyCaptureRegex <- function(mir,r){
  mir <- unlist(apply(mir, 1, function(x) captureRegex(r,x[1])))
  mir <- matrix(mir ,ncol=5, byrow = TRUE)
  mir
}
```

Usage and results:

```
> captureRegex("\\[[a-z0-9]+:([0-9]+):([0-9]+)-([0-9]+):([-+])\\]","[hg19:12:125627828-125627847:-]")
$`[hg19:12:125627828-125627847:-]`
[1] "[hg19:12:125627828-125627847:-]" "12" "125627828" "125627847" "-"   

> applyCaptureRegex(exampleData,"\\[[a-z0-9]+:([0-9]+):([0-9]+)-([0-9]+):([-+])\\]")
     [,1]                              [,2] [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
[1,] "[hg19:21:34809787-34809808:+]"   "21" "34809787"  "34809808"  "+" 
[2,] "[hg19:11:105851118-105851139:+]" "11" "105851118" "105851139" "+" 
[3,] "[hg19:17:7482245-7482266:+]"     "17" "7482245"   "7482266"   "+" 
[4,] "[hg19:6:19839915-19839936:+]"    "6"  "19839915"  "19839936"  "+"
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why in captureRegex are you doing : `sapply(regmatches(str,gregexpr(captRegEx,str))[[1]], function(m) regmatches(m,regexec(captRegEx,m)))` and not simply : `regmatches(str,regexec(captRegEx,str))[[1]]` ?

Comment: I missed the forest for the trees ;)

Comment: Ok, so simply changing `applyCaptureRegex` to the following one-liner you'll get a big boost : `do.call(rbind,lapply(charvecHere,function(x) regmatches(x,regexec(regularExpHere,x))[[1]]))` (even if `str_match` approach is still about 4x faster...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why **reinvent** the wheel? You have several library packages to choose from with functions that return a character matrix with one column for each capturing group in your pattern.

**stri_match_all_regex** — [**stringi**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringi/index.html)

```
x <- c('[hg19:21:34809787-34809808:+]', '[hg19:11:105851118-105851139:+]', '[hg19:17:7482245-7482266:+]', '[hg19:6:19839915-19839936:+]')
do.call(rbind, stri_match_all_regex(x, '\\[[^:]+:(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([-+])]'))
#      [,1]                              [,2] [,3]        [,4]        [,5]
# [1,] "[hg19:21:34809787-34809808:+]"   "21" "34809787"  "34809808"  "+" 
# [2,] "[hg19:11:105851118-105851139:+]" "11" "105851118" "105851139" "+" 
# [3,] "[hg19:17:7482245-7482266:+]"     "17" "7482245"   "7482266"   "+" 
# [4,] "[hg19:6:19839915-19839936:+]"    "6"  "19839915"  "19839936"  "+"
```

**str_match** — [**stringr**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/index.html)

```
str_match(x, '\\[[^:]+:(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([-+])]')
```

**strapplyc** — [**gsubfn**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html)

```
strapplyc(x, "(\\[[^:]+:(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([-+])])", simplify = rbind)
```

Below is a benchmark comparison of all combined solutions.

```
x <- rep(c('[hg19:21:34809787-34809808:+]', 
           '[hg19:11:105851118-105851139:+]', 
           '[hg19:17:7482245-7482266:+]', 
           '[hg19:6:19839915-19839936:+]'), 1000)

applyCaptureRegex <- function(mir, r) {
  do.call(rbind, lapply(mir, function(x) regmatches(x, regexec(r, x))[[1]]))
}

gsubfn <- function(x1) strapplyc(x1, '(\\[[^:]+:(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([-+])])', simplify = rbind)
regmtch <- function(x1) applyCaptureRegex(x1, '\\[[^:]+:(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([-+])]')
stringr <- function(x1) str_match(x1, '\\[[^:]+:(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([-+])]')
stringi <- function(x1) do.call(rbind, stri_match_all_regex(x1, '\\[[^:]+:(\\d+):(\\d+)-(\\d+):([-+])]'))

require(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(gsubfn(x), regmtch(x), stringr(x), stringi(x))
```

Result

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
  gsubfn(x) 372.27072 382.82179 391.21837 388.32396 396.27361 449.03091   100
 regmtch(x) 394.03164 409.87523 419.42936 417.76770 427.08208 456.92460   100
 stringr(x)  65.81644  70.28327  76.02298  75.43162  78.92567 116.18026   100
 stringi(x)  15.88171  16.53047  17.52434  16.96127  17.76007  23.94449   100
```

Comment: I would be idly curious how this compares performance-wise to just doing `strsplit(as.character(exampleData[[1]]),split = ":|-|]")` and then stitching them together using `rbindlist` from **data.table**.

Comment: This would have saved me quiet some time, if I had known about this before. And it is *much* faster indeed. Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: @MineSweeper I assumed `rbindlist` would coerce things as needed, but apparently not. Still, my preliminary checks indicate that even just using `do.call("rbind",...)` is ~40% faster than `str_match`, if you care.

Comment: @joran The faster the better - I have never used a `do.call` for my projects before. Maybe now is the time

Comment: @joran: strsplit approach is really smart and works in this case but probably it's not applicable if you need some more complex reg-exp to tokenize your strings...

Comment: @hwnd: have you seen my answer in chatroom?

Comment: @hwnd: from your benchmark it seems like the first and second functions behave similarly, but actually as the length of the character vector increases, the performance of applyCaptureRegex seems to decrease with respect to the other 2 methods. Try with a vector of thousands of elements  ;)